# MS Access - Positive and Negative values in table are all positive once selected in query

Tags: sql, ms-access, negative-number

I have a field in a table that contains positive and negatives numbers. The field is a number field. I need to be able to sum the field according to ID. It didn't seem to be returning the expected results so I dug a bit deeper. For some reason when I select from the table I only get positive results. Can anyone tell me why this is happening?

This is the SQL statement. Nothing fancy as you can see. XAMT is the number field.

```
SELECT XACCT, 
FROM Table1
WHERE XAMT>0
order by xamt desc
```

XAMT[image: The design view]
Note that I did google this before I posted the question, I just couldn't find anything useful.

Comment: Unless I'm missing something obvious, there aren't any negative numbers greater than 0.

Comment: If you try `SELECT XACCT FROM Table1 WHERE XAMT<0` do you get some result?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Um....pardon me, but that seems like what you're searching for.

```
WHERE XAMT>0
```

This will only give you values above zero. I hope I understood correctly, but it looks like that's your issue here.